# Сглаживание по пяти точкам. Создание списка из другого списка с помощью трёх функций

Tags: python, график

Работая с графиками, наткнулся на одну проблему при работе со списками.
Есть 2 списка, импортированных из колонок excel-файла через xlrd, из них строится график через matplotlib, с этим проблем нет.
Но, чтобы график выглядел лучше, нужно провести операцию сглаживания по пяти точкам, используя формулы:

```
x0средн=(3*x0+2*x1+x2+x4)/5

x1средн=(4*x0+3*x1+2*x2+x3)/10

xnсредн=(xn-2+xn-1+xn+xn+1+xn+2)/5

предпоследний элемент: xN-1 средн=(4*xN+3*xN-1+2*xN-2+xN-3)/10

последний элемент: xNcpедн=(3*xN+2*xN-1+xN-2-xN-4)/5
```

и из этого сделать новый список.

Каким образом сделать такой цикл, чтобы выбрать 4 или 5 значений из списка, пересчитать по соответствующей формуле и отправить полученное значение в новый список?

получается что-то вроде такого:

```
def worker(lst: list) -> list:

    lst[0] = (3*lst[0]+2*lst[0+1]+lst[0+2]-lst[0+4])/5
    return lst


    lst[1] = (4*lst[1]+3*lst[1+1]+2*lst[1+2]+lst[1+3])/10
    return lst

    for i in range(lst[2]; lst[-3]):
        lst[i] = (4*lst[i]+3*lst[i-1]+2*lst[i-2]+lst[i-3])/10
    return lst


    lst[-2] = (4*lst[-2]+3*lst[-2-1]+2*lst[-2-2]+lst[-2-4])/10
    return lst


    lst[-1] = (3*lst[-1]+2*lst[-1-1]+lst[-1-2]-lst[-1-4])/5
    return lst
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def list_parts(lst: list, n: int) -> iter:
    '''поделить список на части'''
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i+n]

def worker(lst: list) -> list:
    '''имитация пересчета по формуле'''
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i] += 11
    return lst

lst = list(range(20))  # исходный список
new_list = []  # измененный список

for part in list_parts(lst, 5):  # цикл, чтобы выбрать 5 значений из списка
    data = worker(part)  # пересчитать по соответствующей формуле
    new_list.extend(data)  # отправить полученное значение в новый список
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ещё один момент: у меня каждому из 5 значений нужно присвоить своё имя, чтобы встать в нужное место в формуле - x0, x1, x2, x3, причем цикл двигается так, что на следующем шаге элемент, который был x1, становится x0, с него идёт отсчёт. Каждый шаг это 4 предыдущих значения, но уже на других местах в формуле и 1 новое. А в последних двух формулах отсчёт идёт уже в другую сторону. И получается, что частей тогда столько же, сколько элементов в списке. Получается типа скользящего среднего, но с разными формулами.